# CL - How is obj argument getting passed into labels function?

Tags: lisp

```
(defparameter *objects* '(whiskey bucket frog chain))

(defparameter *object-locations* '((whiskey living-room)
                                   (bucket living-room)
                                   (chain garden)
                                   (frog garden)))

(defun objects-at (loc objs obj-locs)
  (labels ((at-loc-p (obj)
             (eq (cadr (assoc obj obj-locs)) loc)))
    (remove-if-not #'at-loc-p objs)))

(objects-at 'living-room *objects* *object-locations*)
```

returns `(WHISKEY BUCKET)` in REPL.

How is `obj` getting passed into `at-loc-p`? None of the parameters for `objects-at` is named `obj`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the parameters of `objects-at` is named `obj`, but one of the parameters (in fact the only parameter) of `at-loc-p` is. So when `at-loc-p` is called with an argument (by `remove-if-not`), that argument will be passed to `at-loc-p` with the name `obj`.

Comment: Doooh, didn't notice it was calling the function with objs as the argument after labels. Thanks for the concise explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`labels` defines functions. So

```
(labels ((square (x) (* x x))) (square 2))
```

is the same as

```
(let ((square (lambda (x) (* x x)))) (funcall square 2))
```

and `x` (in your example, `obj`) is just the name of the parameter to the `square` (`at-loc-p`) function.

Another way of writing your function `objects-at` is

```
(defun objects-at (loc objs obj-locs)
  (defun at-loc-p (obj)
    (eq (cadr (assoc obj obj-locs)) loc))
  (remove-if-not #'at-loc-p objs)))
```

except that this globally defines the function `at-loc-p`.

Comment: Note though that in your last code snippet, you're defining `at-loc-p` as a global function that's visible from outside of `objects-at`. That's not the same thing `labels` does.